# Perl Script: sorting through log files.

Tags: perl, scripting, grep

Trying to write a script which opens a directory and reads bunch of multiple log files line by line and search for information such as example: 
 "Attendance = 0 " previously I have used `grep "Attendance ="` `*` to search my information but trying to write a script to search for my information. 
Need your help to finish this task.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

  use strict;
  use warnings;
  my $dir = '/path/';
  opendir (DIR, $dir) or die $!;
  while (my $file = readdir(DIR))
   {
   print "$file\n";
   }
   closedir(DIR);
   exit 0;
```

Comment: First of all, use spaces and blank lines to reveal the structure of your code. It's a little rude to post code like that when you're asking for help with it. Didn't you notice that your program doesn't look like most of the others that you see? Tale a look at [`perldoc perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) for the rules that most people follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use `File::Find::Rule` for things like this. It preserves path information, and it's easy to use. Here's an example that does what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = '/path/';
my $type = '*';

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name($type)
                            ->in(($dir));

for my $file (@files){

    print "$file\n\n";

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "can't open $file: $!";

    while (my $line = <$fh>){
        if ($line =~ /Attendance =/){
            print $line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the double parentheses: `->in($dir)` is OK.

Answer (score 1):

What's your perl experience?

I'm assuming each file is a text file. I'll give you a hint. Try to figure out where to put this code.

```
# Now to open and read a text file.
my $fn='file.log';
# $! is a variable which holds a possible error msg.
open(my $INFILE, '<', $fn) or die "ERROR: could not open $fn. $!";
my @filearr=<$INFILE>; # Read the whole file into an array.
close($INFILE);

# Now look in @filearr, which has one entry per line of the original file.

exit; # Normal exit
```